# How can I get xref files into the output created by Oxygen XML Editor's Transformation?

Tags: dita

I have some XML files that are referenced by a .ditamap file that I run through Oxygen XML Editor's Transformation process.  Inside one of these XML files is:

```
[<b><xref href="aFile.html" scope="external">Some Text</xref></b>]
```

aFile.html does not get placed in the transformed output.  How can I make this happen?

I did try the *object* tag instead of *xref*, and that did cause aFile.html to appear in the output, but it embedded a scrollable window in my page, and I want a hyperlink to a file.

**UPDATE 1:**  A) I added the format and removed the scope attributes, but there was no difference.

```
[<b><xref href="aFile.html" format="html">Some Text</xref></b>]
```

B) I added scope local, but there was no difference.

```
[<b><xref href="aFile.html" format="html" scope="local">Some Text</xref></b>]
```

**UPDATE 2:** I am using version 21 of the tool and the DITA Map WebHelp Classic (deprecated) Transformation Scenario.

Comment: Try adding `format="html"` attribute for `xref` element.

Comment: @tmakita I added an update.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: What transformation scenario are you trying?

Comment: @tmakita, please see Update 2 for the answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove scope=external attribute and add instead format=html attribute. Files referenced with scope external are not copied to output folder.

Comment: Oxygen XML editor version? Html5 or xhtml output? Any customizations that you made to publishing engine?

Comment: Please see Update 2 for the answer to your question.  No customizations.

Comment: I rebooted my PC (thus restarting Oxygen) and Update 1 A worked.

Comment: I have a related, but different question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741255/in-oxygen-xml-editor-can-i-automatically-xcopy-a-folder-to-my-transformations if you can answer that, too, please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the referenced HTML file is in the same folder as the source dita files. If not, the OT does not pick

Comment: Thank you, but the href attribute contains no directory/folder, so it is already in the same folder as the source XML files.