# In Oxygen XML Editor, can I automatically xcopy a folder to my Transformation's output folder?

Tags: dita

I am using version 21 of the Oxygen XML Editor and the DITA Map WebHelp Classic (deprecated) Transformation Scenario.  I have a folder that contains HTML files I want to open in a new window/tab, so that are xref'd in my XML file such as:

```
[<b><xref href="External/aFile.html" format="html" scope="external">Some Text</xref></b>]
```

I have a PostProcess batch script that I manually run that does an xcopy of the External folder to Oxygen's out/webhelp folder, and I would like to instead run it automatically in Oxygen after the Transformation is done.  Is there I way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1) Use your custom ANT build file in the Oxygen transformation scenario:
To use a custom build file in a DITA-OT transformation, follow these steps:

- Use the Configure Transformation Scenario(s) action to open the Configure Transformation Scenario(s) dialog box.
- Select the transformation scenario and click Edit.
- Go to the Advanced tab and change the Custom build file path to point to the custom build file.

As an example, if you want to call a custom script before running the DITA OT, your custom build file would have the following content:

```
<project basedir="." default="dist">
<!--The DITA OT default build file-->
 <import file="path/to/DITA-OT3.x/build.xml"/>
 <target name="dist">
   <!--Call the DITA OT default target-->
   <antcall target="init"/>
  <!-- You could run your script here -->
  <!--<copy></copy>-->
 </target>
</project>
```

2) Create your own DITA Open Toolkit plugin which adds a new transformation type with a custom ANT build file which calls the WebHelp transformation type and afterwards can perform the copy operation:

https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/21.1/ug-editor/topics/whr-xslt-customization.html